# Issue executing a full sentence in loop

Tags: java, for-loop

My method is supposed to print out a statement for a certain number of times; however, it only will print out one word of an inputed statement when I need to a whole sentence to be printed. 
Example: When I try to put in "It is a nice day", it will only output the word "It" instead of the whole sentence.

```
public static void  repeat(){
                System.out.println("Please input a number");
                Scanner inputRepeat = new Scanner(System.in); 
                int r = inputRepeat.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter a sentence to repeat: "); 
                String sentence = inputRepeat.next(); 
                for(int i = 0; i <= r; i++){
                    System.out.println(sentence); 
                }
```

Comment: Use `nextLine` instead of `next`

Comment: The [scanner documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is an excellent resource.

Comment: You probably need nextLine or a similar method instead of input.next

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only prints the first word is because `Scanner` uses whitespace as a delimiter by default, so it only accepts the first word in your line. To accomplish what you want, use `Scanner.nextLine()`, like so:

```
public static void  repeat(){
                System.out.println("Please input a number");
                Scanner inputRepeat = new Scanner(System.in); 
                int r = inputRepeat.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter a sentence to repeat: "); 
                String sentence = inputRepeat.nextLine(); 
                for(int i = 0; i <= r; i++){
                    System.out.println(sentence); 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `next()` will only return what comes before a space. `nextLine()` automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line. As your line consist of spaces you need to use `nextLine()` to read the line.
So change

```
String sentence = inputRepeat.next();
```

to

```
String sentence = inputRepeat.nextLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

your String sentence = inputRepeat.next();  has to go in the loop

Comment: `inputRepeat.next();` should be outside the loop. Program is to read a sentence and print it `r` times. So if its inside it will read `r` lines.